# Animating the width of an html element

Tags: javascript, animation

How can I make a function that will increase (decrease) the width of a given html element? Below is my attempt at doing this, but I think this is very bad. How can I improve my code?

```js
function foo(elem, num) {
  var i = 0;

  if (!elem.style.width) {
    setTimeout(function bar() {
      if (i < num) {
        elem.style.width = i++ + '%';
        elem.innerHTML = i++;
      }

      setTimeout(bar, 30);
    }, 30);
  } else {
    i = num;
    setTimeout(function baz() {
      if (i > 0) {
        elem.style.width = i-- + '%';
        elem.innerHTML = i--;
      }

      setTimeout(baz, 30);
    }, 30);
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="foo(this, 75)">0%</div>
```

Comment: Other than being able to use libraries, this is a pretty valid approach. Also, I'd use `setInterval` and clear it when done, rather than `setTimeout`, but thst's just me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few improvements to be made:

- first, you are currently skipping every second percentage because you are executing `i++`/`i--` twice in your function, one after the other (so you're setting the width to `0%` and displaying `1%` and then setting it to `2%` and displaying `3%`, etc)
- second, you can use `requestAnimationFrame` (for older browsers include the polyfill) to get much better performance
- third, you can restructure your code so that it's not so repetitive by computing a direction (`1` or `-1` depending on if you want `i` to increase or decrease) and only having one `bar`/`baz` function

Here's my take on it:

```js
function foo(elem, num) {
  var initialWidth = elem.style.width;
  var i = initialWidth ? num : 0;
  var direction = initialWidth ? -1 : 1;

  function bar() {
    elem.style.width = i + '%';
    elem.innerHTML = '' + i;
    i += direction;

    if (i <= num && i >= 0)
      window.requestAnimationFrame(bar);
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(bar);

  return function reset() {
    elem.style.width = initialWidth;
    elem.innerHTML = '';
  }
}


var animated = false,
  reset1, reset2;
document.getElementsByClassName('grower-parent')[0].onclick = function() {
  if (!animated) {
    animated = true;
    reset1 = foo(document.getElementsByClassName('grower-1')[0], 50);
    reset2 = foo(document.getElementsByClassName('grower-2')[0], 50);
    return;
  }
  animated = false;
  reset1();
  reset2();
};
```

```css
.grower-1,
.grower-2 {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 1em;
  color: white;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grower-parent">
  <div class="grower-1" style="width:50%"></div>
  <div class="grower-2"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** now first click starts the animation and the second click resets it.

**Edit 2:** a much more complex program that can actually toggle between animating towards a goal or going back towards the initial value (and switching between `px` and `%` units). You can now start seeing why we have *dedicated* animation libraries that we can just plug into our projects to not have to reinvent the wheel :) (try [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com), it's awesome)

```js
function animateTo(element, to) {
  if (to === undefined) return function() {};

  var animating = true;
  var width, match;
  var unit = (to === Number(to)) ? (width = to, 'px') : (match = to.match(/(\d+)\s*(px|%)/), width = Number(match[1]), match[2]);
  var initialWidth = unit === 'px' ? element.offsetWidth : (match = element.style.width.match(/(\d+)\s*%/)) ? Number(match[1]) : Math.round(element.offsetWidth / ((element.offsetParent || element).offsetWidth) * 100);
  var currentWidth = initialWidth;
  var direction = initialWidth <= width ? 1 : -1;

  function animate() {
    element.style.width = currentWidth + unit;
    element.innerHTML = currentWidth + unit;
    currentWidth += direction;

    if (direction * currentWidth <= direction * width) {
      if (animating) window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    } else {
      animating = false;
    }
  }

  function stopAnimation() {
    animating = false;
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  return stopAnimation;
}

function toggleWidth(element, to) {
  var initial = element.style.width ? element.style.width : element.offsetWidth + 'px';
  var toAnimation = true;
  var stopAnimation;
  return function toggle() {
    if (stopAnimation) stopAnimation();
    if (toAnimation) {
      stopAnimation = animateTo(element, to);
    } else {
      stopAnimation = animateTo(element, initial);
    }
    toAnimation = !toAnimation;
  }
}

var toggle = toggleWidth(document.getElementsByClassName('grower-1')[0], '10%');
var toggle2 = toggleWidth(document.getElementsByClassName('grower-2')[0], '200px');
document.getElementsByClassName('grower-parent')[0].onclick = function() {
  toggle();
  toggle2();
};
```

```css
.grower-1,
.grower-2 {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 1em;
  color: white;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grower-parent">
  <div class="grower-1" style="width:400px"></div>
  <div class="grower-2" style="width:5%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! And how to make the element after the second click takes the original width?

Comment: Which second click? Do you want them to return  to their original widths when clicked? (kind of hard when they get to 0% width for example, as there's nothing to click on - it's probably easier to put the click event on a parent element or a button or somesuch. And you can just remember the previous value of the width and reset it

Comment: >  Do you want them to return to their original widths when clicked?

Yes.

Comment: Ionut Costica, sorry my English, but I need this: http://plnkr.co/edit/tYbbE4VnCA4zlY0gVjQa?p=preview

Comment: And the second click is necessary that the interest displayed in div

Comment: Ionut Costica, how to do that at the second click when the width decreases in the number in div was 0 at the end?

http://plnkr.co/edit/1sd8XyfMyz8rHvvcxrL4?p=preview

Comment: You can force an initial width for the toggle functions if you replace the initialWidth variable with a parameter (don't compute it in the toggleWidth but pass it in as a parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [CSS Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)?

```js
$(function() {

  $('#myButton').on('click', function() {
    
    $('#myDiv').addClass('transition-class');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style> 
    div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
        transition: width 2s;
    }
    
    div:hover {
        width: 300px;
    }
    .transition-class {
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>
    
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    
    <p>Hover over the div element above, to see the transition effect.</p>
    
     <button id="myButton">click me</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: No. I forgot to say, I need to native JavaScript.

Comment: No. Only native JavaScript. No CSS, no Jquery.

Comment: you can do all that I did manipulating de DOM with JS.. the only difference is that I am manipulating with CSS..